# SSLHandshakeException: CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found

Tags: android, retrofit, okhttp, android-network-security-config

I'm getting the error in the title. Where might the problem be?

`

```
interface QuizService {
    @GET("quiz")
    fun getQuizQuestions(): Call<List<Question>>

    companion object {
        private const val BASE_URL = "https://asdasd.mockable.io/"


        fun create(): QuizService {
            val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build()

            return retrofit.create(QuizService::class.java)
        }
    }
}`
```

I added the network settings to the AndroidManifest.xml file as follows. However, the problem was not resolved.

`<application android:networkSecurityConfig="@xml/network_security_config" ... .. .`

network_security_config.xml

`

```
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="false">
    <!-- Make sure your URL Server here -->
    <domain includeSubdomains="true">mockable.io</domain>
    <trust-anchors>
        <certificates src="user" />
        <certificates src="system" />
    </trust-anchors>
</domain-config>
```

`

Comment: Your network security config only allows cleartext traffic (not relevant for https URLs) and user certificates, but you did not write something about installing the used root CA as user cert.